# Not saving HTML Map - Interactive map Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, maps, folium

I'm trying to make an interactive map in Python.

I'm saving the map as HTML, it should be saved in the folder where I have my script, the problem is that I don't see it, apparently did not save it. But when I run the script, I don't have any error message.

This is the script:

```
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd 
import math 
import folium
from folium import Choropleth, Circle, Marker
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster

#m_1 = folium.Map(location=[-34.8214, -56.2267], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10)   
m_1 = folium.Map(location=[42.32,-71.0589], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10)

m_1.save('m1.html')
```

Comment: Ciao Valentina, are you sure you are controlling the right directory? The code works.

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure.

Comment: Which version of folium do you have currently?

Comment: I currently have folium==0.10.1. Do you recommend uninstall and install any other previous version?

Comment: Not at all. Your code works perfectly. You have an updated version. There has to be a very stupid mix-up. Are you working on jupyter notebook?

Comment: No, im working with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What happens by changing the path? I mean this line `m_1.save('m1.html')`.

Comment: I have tried in different paths but never works :(

Comment: Could you run your code from command line? I mean, save that code as try,py, and then run `python3 run.py`. And see if you find the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i run the code from CDM and did work.

Comment: Why do you think i have to do this? is there a way that i can run my code from Visual studio and also get the results?

Comment: It is likely to be a problem about the configuration of your IDE.